# Task with loop in Argo workflow

Tags: for-loop, workflow, argoproj

I want to introduce a for loop in a workflow that consists of 2 individual tasks. The second will be dependent on the first. Each one should use different templates. The second should iterate with `{{item}}`. For each iteration I want to know if the default is to execute only the second task or it will re-execute the whole flow?

Answer (score 1):

To repeat the second step only, use `withItems`/`withParameter` (there is no `withArtifact`, though you can get the same behavior with `data`). These loops repeat the specific step they are mentioned in for the specified items/parameter only.

Comment: thanx! I was thinking of introducing the withItems outside my DAG somehow, so as to execute both tasks in parallel. The constraint is that each time task2 has task1 as dependency

Answer (score 1):

```
- name: create-resources
  inputs:
      paramet`enter code here`ers:
        - name: env
        - name: giturl
        - name: resources
        - name: awssecret
  dag:
    tasks:
      - name: resource
        template: resource-create
        arguments:
          parameters:
          - name: env
            value: "{{inputs.parameters.env}}"
          - name: giturl
            value: "{{inputs.parameters.giturl}}"  
          - name: resource
            value: "{{item}}"
          - name: awssecret
            value: "{{inputs.parameters.awssecret}}"   
        withParam: "{{inputs.parameters.resources}}"
        #############   For parallel execution use steps ##############
  steps:
  - - name: resource
      template: resource-create
      arguments:
        parameters:
        - name: env
          value: "{{inputs.parameters.env}}"
        - name: giturl
          value: "{{inputs.parameters.giturl}}"  
        - name: resource
          value: "{{item}}"
        - name: awssecret
          value: "{{inputs.parameters.awssecret}}"   
      withParam: "{{inputs.parameters.resources}}"
```

Comment: although its not executing in a dependency format but it solves the problem of parallel and make it sequential.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.